# Common view in all tab views in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

I have a small view (showing application version & name on top of screen) which needs to be displayed in all tab views. I am trying to add these things in App.xaml along with application bar (Global) but it seems it is not the correct approach. If anyone have any idea please share.

Thanks .. !

Answer (score 0):

If it is a tabbed view I am assuming you are using a Pivot control. How about then displaying your small view with the Pivot's title, or then above the pivot?

Comment: No... i m not using pivot control..
But will try with ur suggetion